# Create a form in c#

Tags: c#

Can I create a form from a console application? If yes then how?

Comment: Do you want to create a brand new form or load an existing one?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.

You need to reference the [`System.Windows.Forms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.aspx) assembly and add the namespace to your code.

Then you new up a [`Form`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx) and [`Show`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.show.aspx) it.

You will not have designer support and will have to manually create and add controls etc...

If you already have a ready form class in another assembly, you could use that, simply following the same steps (add reference, add namespace, new up and show).

Answer (score 2):

Add reference to System.Windows.Forms, and then import it's namespace. Then you can create forms.

Answer (score 1):

If your question about dynamic form creation just folow answer provided by `Oded` and `AtoMerZ`. If you want create it with graphic designer just add Windows form in your console project and all references would added to project automaticaly

Answer (score 1):

Yes. and the soultion:

It is realy so clear.

You need to add `System.Windows.Forms` in first step.If you don't know how just open the `solution explorer` right click on `references` and then `add reference`. In the dialog that apears and in `.Net tab` select `System.Windows.Forms` from list and click ok.

then this is a sample code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

    namespace ConsoleApplication
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.Form MyForm = new System.Windows.Forms.Form();            
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(MyForm);

            }
        }
    }
```

I think you may need a c# book. :)

Comment: The [STAThread] attribute is *required* on the Main() method.  Enabling visual styles would be wise too.  It's not *that* clear.